# Created firebase app with wrong bundle id, how can I move the data to the correct bundle id?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've looked on SO and it seems that there is no way to move data to a different bundle ID with firebase. This is an issue since I have analytics data for the app going to the incorrect bundle id which causes issues with push messaging.

Is there any way I can change the bundle id or export the data into a new firebase app?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you find a way out?